# Meaning of "Run To My Rescue" - Shogun feat. Emma Lock

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In this song has those lines

> [Our loves a stone throw away 
>   
>  We get so near
>   
>  But weve still so far away
>   
>  Concealed behind all our floored disguises](http://www.metrolyrics.com/run-to-my-rescue-original-mix-lyrics-shogun.html)

So what does mean **Our loves a stone throw away?**

Answer (score 1):

There are several typos on that link from Metrolyrics.

I think the exact transcription is:

> Our love'**s** a stone throw away
>   We get so near
>   But we'**re** still so far away
>   Concealed behind all our floored disguises

A "stone throw" is an english expression that means a "short distance". It means that their love is a short distance (the distance an person can throw a stone, a few dozens of meters) but yet not close enough.

This [SongLyrics.com link](http://www.songlyrics.com/shogun-emma-lock/run-to-my-rescue-original-mix-edit-lyrics) has the correct transcription.